# Toolbar not display in lollipop version

Tags: android

I implemented parallax effect in my app with nested scrollview and toolbar everything goes fine. but when i install my app in lollipop version then UI is change and toolbar is not display. it properly display in other versions of android.

```
my code: main xml file

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_event_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Confirmation_relativelayout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_event_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="5dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
                app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/black" >


                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                        tools:context=".MainActivity">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/Main_Relative_layout"
                            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            >

                            <com.oi.managemygroup.util.SelectableRoundedImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView_event_image_aedl"
                                android:layout_width="90dp"
                                android:layout_height="90dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_event_new"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option"
                                app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option"
                                app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option"
                                app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="@dimen/corner_radius_for_ask_option" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_event_name_aedl"
                                android:layout_width="180dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_event_image_aedl"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_Event_participated_count_aedl"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="23dp"
                                android:text="8"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_responsecount"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:maxLength="3"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_event_name_aedl"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView_Event_total_count_aedl"
                                android:layout_width="25dp"
                                android:layout_height="23dp"
                                android:text="10"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_response_count_gray"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="14sp"
                                android:maxLength="3"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Event_participated_count_aedl"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView_event_name_aedl"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                />

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/view1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_event_image_aedl"
                                android:background="#E8E8E8" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_event_details"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar_eventdetails_screen" />
                <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
....
....
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>





Tool bar xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/AppCompatTheme.Toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    android:windowBackground="@android:color/white">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_actionbar_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_button"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it by removing nestedScrollView or any other things. Please post your debugging results too

Comment: i solved this issue by updating android support library.

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar-animation-using-design-support-library/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by updating android support library.